# I want to hover(show and hide) multiple ids with different texts over dots

Tags: jquery

I want to hover(mouseover and mouseout) text over dots. each dot has different text.

I have done this task by hard coding. But I want to make it precise and short. I want to do this work by a unique ID and same classes.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.colors').hide();
  $(function() {
    $('#mapselector').change(function() {
      $('.colors').hide();
      $('.text').hide();
      $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
      $('.box').mouseover(function() {
        $('.text').show();
      });
      $('.box').mouseout(function() {
        $('.text').hide();
      });
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <Select id="mapselector" class="custom-select bg-warning">
    <option>Select Options</option>
    <option value="asia">Asia</option>
  </Select>
</div>
<div id="asia" class="colors" style="display:none">
  <div id="pin-1" class="box">
    <div id="pin-text1" class="text" value="Islam">
      <p class="h6 pt-3 pr-5">Islamabad</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="pin-2" class="box">
    <div id="pin-text2" class="text">
      <p class="h6  pt-3 pr-5">Afghan</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="pin-3" class="box">
    <div id="pin-text3" class="text">
      <p class="h6 pt-3 pr-5 ">Delhi</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

When I hover over single Dot So it shows all text over dot(Islamabad, Delhi, Afghan).
I want to display each text over a specific dot.

[Output Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rWIdt.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code

```
      $('.box').mouseover(function() {
        $('.text').show();
      });
      $('.box').mouseout(function() {
        $('.text').hide();
      });
```

shows all '.text' div when you hover '.box' div. You have to differentiate like this

```
  $('.box').mouseover(function() {
    $(this).find('.text').show();
  });
  $('.box').mouseout(function() {
    $(this).find('.text').hide();
  });
```

Comment: Note that you could join both event handlers together using `on()` and `toggle()`